# CREATE SCHEMA without permission in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created a new schema in SQL Server using

```
CREATE SCHEMA testschema
```

I checked `database_principals` table using

```
 select * from mssql.sys.database_principals;
```

I did not find any entry for testschema.

Did I miss something?

I am able to access tables in the `dbo` schema. I want to create testschema with same privilege as `dbo`.

Connection String for JDBC :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;databaseName=BCHN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE SCHEMA does not create database principal.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.schemas
    WHERE
        name = 'testschema'
```

As you can see: principal_id = 1 (dbo)

It must be possible to access objects in your schema with [schema_name].[object_name]

Answer (score 1):

IIRC up to SQL Server 2000 schemas and principals were not distinguished. If you work on 2005 or higher, the new schema should display with the statement

```
select * from sys.schemas
```